# How to fix broken repositories for `apt update`

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux, apt

I'm in a Kali Linux Virtual machine on a Windows 10 host machine. 
When I try use `sudo apt update`, I get the following output:

[image: Screenshot output sudo apt update]

The strange thing is that the error comes from a repository from a release that's not "Kali".
 How can I fix this?

Comment: Restart, sudo apt autoremove -y , restart again and try updating.

Comment: The repositories are in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (a file) or as separate files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` *(Ubuntu 20.04)*... `$ apt-add-repository --help` is relevant also (look for `--remove`).

Comment: John: your comment didn't work.
Hannu: I've looked into the `sources.list.d` directory and deleted everything that had something to do with `hirsute`. Now I can update. Could this give problems in the long term?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the kali docs: [Non-Kali repositories](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/)

> adding other operating system's repositories into Kali (such as trying to put Ubuntu on Kali), will break your installation. This is the single most common reason why Kali Linux systems break. ​ If any guides are telling you to do anything else than the above, this is unofficial advice, and completely not supported by Kali Linux. More often than not, users in this case end up doing a reinstall after learning this lesson.

Some repositories can be added safely to Kali Linux but not all. To solve the problem keep only the official repository:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" |\
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```